# What do I do with "._" files?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, usb-flash-drive, chkdsk, help-files

I used "chkdsk X: /f" for the drive "E:", which is an external USB flash drive. It said it is formatted in FAT32 and then said that Windows can't use it because it already is being used by another process (Nothing from the flash drive was opened). It then asked if I wanted to dismount it and I put no and then asked if I wanted it to do that later and I put no. After that it went back to "C:\Users\class>". I typed "ATTRIB -H -R -S /S /D X:*.*". Then went to check the drive. While it did give me older versions of files, they begin with "._" and when I try opening them, it is either shown with random symbols and characters or asking to be fixed first. Additionally it created new folders such as "System Volume Information". What should I do with these files?

Comment: Files starting with ._ are made my Macs, and generally only include additional metadata/resource forks for the files on your drive. They're set to be hidden, so I believe you have unhidden them.

Comment: I am not using a mac, only windows 10. So should I just type in command prompt, "attrib +H [asterisk].[asterisk]" (asterisks don't show up when typed) to reverse my action?